# ActiveX method is not found

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, activex

I have this C# code of ActiveX and testing it under IE9 (IE is configured to download AxtiveX without any restrictions)

```
namespace Sactivex
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Spc class
    /// </summary>
    [ProgId("Sactivex.Spc")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
    [Guid("12BD177A-3BB2-434D-84CF-5A05A58CF6FF")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    static public class Spc
    {
        [ComVisible(true)]
        static public string GetData()
        {
            try
            {
                string result = "Test name 1:1#Test name 2:2#Test name 3:3#Test name 4:4#Test name 5:5#Test name 6:6#Test name 7:7#Test name 8:8#Test name 9:9#Test name 10:10#Test name 11:11";

                return result;
            }
            catch 
            {                
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

It is signed with certificate and loads properly.

```
   <div style="display:none;">
        <OBJECT id="DemoActiveX" classid="clsid:12BD177A-3BB2-434D-84CF-5A05A58CF6FF" codebase="Sactivex.cab"></OBJECT>
    </div>
```

When I call the static method of the static class I am facing this error

> Cannot obtain property 'GetData', it is null or is not defined.

[image]
Any clue?

Comment: Would your code to call the function not just be:

    Sactivx.SPC.GetData()

 Seeing as they are all static?

Comment: @BenSteele Hi. Your solution does not work. Sorry.